Why Kafka Connect ReplaceField SMT does not work after flatten SMT
I have nested avro record and I am using flatten and ReplaceField(RenameField) SMT in JDBC sink connector, auto create , auto evolve is true, not table is getting created with columns which is like actoruser_department, actoruser_email , that means my RenameField SMT is not taking effect , could not able to find why that would be , any suggestions please.
Here is transformation I have in my JDBC sink connector
“transforms”: “flatten,renameField”, “transforms.flatten.type”: “org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value”, “transforms.flatten.delimiter”: “_”, “transforms.renameField.type”: “org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value”, “transforms.renameField.renames”: “actoruser_department:department,actoruser_email:email”
Here is the input record look like
{ “actorUser”:{ “department”:“IT”, “email":"xxx.yyy@fff.com” } } 
The order of SMT is correct and it should work as expected , as chain of SMT but result is not as expected, parent and child record keys with _ delimiter for column name is getting created in sink table.
